# Flutter - ListView.builder: Initial scroll position

Tags: listview, flutter, dart, chat, native

I want to setup the initial scroll position of a ListView.builder, I want the list to start at the bottom `0.0`

If I setup `reverse` on the listView of course I get the initial scroll position to be the desired one, but what I need is to have the last children on the bottom, is a chat app.

This is the list builder, `MessageItem()` is the chat message

```dart
ListView.builder(
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    controller: _scrollController,
                    itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) =>
                        MessageItem(
                            index: index,
                            document: snapshot.data.documents[index],
                            myId: myId));
```

This is the animation I have when someone  `send` the message

```dart
_scrollController.animateTo(
                _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent,
                duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                curve: Curves.easeOut);
```

the animation works okay.

---

What I want is the list scroll position to be already at the bottom when the user enters the chat room.

Comment: Would using  a duration of 0 milliseconds work?

Comment: why not set the intial position of the scroll controller in the initState of the widget. this way in the intial widget build it'll scroll to the bottom position.

Comment: @E.Bradford 
Well, that is just an animation that happens when the user press the "send message" button, that works. I tried putting the animation code on `initState()` but it throws error: 

```
I/flutter (15097): ScrollController not attached to any scroll views.
I/flutter (15097): 'package:flutter/src/widgets/scroll_controller.dart':
I/flutter (15097): Failed assertion: line 110 pos 12: '_positions.isNotEmpty'
```
Where should I put it so it can be triggered at the beginning?

Comment: @Salma. tried that, i get an error.

Comment: set it to 0.0 while initializing the scrollController >>>  _scrollController = new ScrollController(                        
      initialScrollOffset: 0.0,                                      
      keepScrollOffset: true,                                        
    );

Comment: @Salma.
It doesn't seem to work, perhaps is because the `ListView` is a builder, `ListView.builder` ,  so that is why I need to setup the animation as: `_scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent` instead of `0.0` but of course this causes an error, it needs some `mounting` I guess.

Comment: just change the index to snapshot.data.length-index-1

Answer (score 28):

for avoid error where scroll isnt attached for any list, use, WidgetsBinding to pullout after build is ready.

```
void _scrollToBottom() {
    if (_scrollController.hasClients) {
      _scrollController.animateTo(_scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent,
          duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300), curve: Curves.elasticOut);
    } else {
      Timer(Duration(milliseconds: 400), () => _scrollToBottom());
    }
 }

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

  WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => _scrollToBottom());

  {...} //rest of code;
}
```

Comment: Not sure why this answer didn't get more love. This solved a problem I've been having with selecting checkboxes in a ListView and keeping the view static, instead of always jumping back to top. Thanks!

Answer (score 19):

You can set one of [ScrollController's](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScrollController-class.html) property: [initialScrollOffset](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScrollController/initialScrollOffset.html)

But on the condition that you know the offset position of the target item/index.

```
ScrollController _controller = ScrollController(initialScrollOffset: itemHeight * index)
```

(*note that this example assumes that the sizes of your list's widgets are of constant size, but if you don't have constant widget sizes in your list, then you must be able to calculate the final offset position of your target item - and that is a whole other issue*)

Or, if you want it to always be the last item/index, then it's much easier:

```
ScrollController _controller = ScrollController(initialScrollOffset: _controller.position.maxScrollExtent)
```

Comment: You can't use _controller while constructing it

Comment: @maff for that there is a special method - addpostframecallback, it is fired right after the widget tree is built so you don't have to guess the delay in the initstate.

Comment: @maff agree with you, but you could have a check something like this
```if(_controller.hasClients){ <Then Scroll to desired positon>}```

Comment: initialOffset will not animate to the position

Comment: This actually works perfectly, you gotta calculate the offset and pass it as parameter. I tested it and works perfectly

Answer (score 8):

The solution for me was:

```
SingleChildScrollView(
                reverse: true,
                child: Container(),
              ),
```

ListView has also reverse property.

Comment: Also you should reverse your array message.

Answer (score 3):

I feel your pain as it is an essential requirement because there could be tens of thousands of messages in a single chat.

To tackle that you can use

```
SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_){});
```

This callback is fired right after the widget tree is built, so you can just

```
scrollController.jump(scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent);
```

That however won't work if you have messages appear asynchronously, that is, after the initstate with some function that pulls it off from firestore document for instance.
In this case you will first need for them to load, and only then do the steps above. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

There is something simple assume that you are getting a list from API in future builder and returning the listview.builder

```
snapshot.data.length-index-1
```

remove the reverse property from the listview.builder

Answer (score -2):

You can also simply use the `FixedExtentScrollController` for same size items with the index of your `initialItem` :

```
controller: FixedExtentScrollController(initialItem: itemIndex);
```

The documentation : *Creates a scroll controller for scrollables whose items have the same size.*

Comment: At the moment "FixedExtentScrollController can only be used with ListWheelScrollViews". Ref: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/28012