# Flutter - Listview.builder set initial offset to last position or pixel?

Tags: flutter, dart

this is definitely similar to [Flutter - ListView.builder: Initial scroll position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57504040/flutter-listview-builder-initial-scroll-position) but it seems there is no solution to it.

I know I can set the initial offset to a double, but what I want is the controller.position.maxScrollExtent.

this is for a chat page, how can WhatsApp and other apps so it so easy while we have to do workarounds for this simple thing?

This will not work > `_chatScrollController = ScrollController(initialScrollOffset: _chatScrollController.position.maxScrollExtent);` because the controller just initialized and it doesn't know the max offset yet. So what I ended up having to do, was to use animateTo after the chat was rebuilt. But I don't like this much. Is there a better way?

Comment: Hi. Check and try my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61034585/flutter-listview-scroll-to-bottom-on-build/61036037#61036037. See the UPDATE part. If it works for you, I make an answer in this question.

Comment: yeah this is what I am currently doing... although this is also the same as adding a function after the listview builds. I don't like this kind of workaround.

Answer (score 0):

You are right. Until the first build of the widget containing the `ListView`  the `ScrollPosition` is not yet attached to `ScrollController`, i.e. `hasClients` returns `false`. And you need to do the following::

```dart
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  _chatScrollController = ScrollController()
  WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
    _chatScrollController.jumpTo(_chatScrollController.position.maxScrollExtent);
  });
}
```